# JavaScript argument syntax like {video: true}

Tags: javascript

From this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) I found a strange syntax for passing parameter as `navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, ...)`. What is this syntax of passing parameter as `{video: true, audio: true}` called?

While this syntax `navigator.getUserMedia("audio, video", ...)` also works, which one should we prefer?

I found the [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891202/what-is-this-javascript-parameter-syntax-called) but the answer accepted there says its an  ActionScript syntax.

Comment: That is called an _object literal_.  JavaScript objects can be expressed as key : value pairs inside `{}`.

Comment: @Satya Close, it's a JavaScript object. JSON would be the corresponding string representation of that object: `'{"video":true,"audio":true}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `{...}` is creating an object literal. In this case, they happen to be constructing the object literal as a parameter.

This is similar to executing a function and passing it's return value as a parameter:

```
navigator.getUserMedia(foo(), ...)

var foo = function () {
    var someObj = {video: true, audio: true};

    return someObj;
};
```

The benefits of passing an object literal is that it allows you to pass multiple logically related arguments together as one formal parameter. This allows dynamic arguments, which could also be achieved by using the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), though most people prefer passing objects as it is easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
{video: true, audio: true}
```

is a JavaScript object literal. One of the main uses is passing a list of options to a function.

As far as which of the two options to use, I'd prefer the object literal syntax because it's the more intuitive of the two: you can see that they're both going to be set to true.